# In C++, how do I take a string formatted like "######" and store each character as an integer?

Tags: c++, string, integer

My function takes a large number as input, in the form of a string. I need to store each number in an integer array, but have been unable to do so. When I do a for loop and make array[i] = string[i], it saves the number as its ascii value. I've been trying to convert this number from its ascii value to an integer, but I cant get atoi to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since the numerals `'0'`-`'9'` are required to be encoded consecutivly in base character set, the numeric value of a numeral character `c` is simply `c - '0'`.

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but clearly when I did, I did something wrong. Thanks for the answer!